# Name of theorem that links uniform distributions with the CDF of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I found the following excerpt from [this page](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~deveritt/networksimulation/rv.pdf):

> Let X be the random variable we are interested in generating, and let
>   F(x) be its distribution  function, ie
>
> $F(x) = Pr\{X ≤ x\}$
>
> There is a **theorem** which says that, if F(x) is continuous, then F(X) is
>   uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1). This can be used to
>   generate random variables with specified distributions.

What's the name of this theorem or can someone show me a reference?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem you're looking for apparently goes under the name of [the probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform). The inverse of this result, i.e. that $F^{-1}(U)$ is distributed like $X$ if $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, is what [inversion sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) is based on.